# Java card weird response to long AID and Short AID applets

Tags: javacard, globalplatform

I create a package that contains 22 equal applets.(The applets are equal in program and different in AID.)

[image]

When I set the package AID and applet's AIDs as below, everything is OK. (I can install it and I can see it in the response of `gp -list` command)

> Package AID = 0102030405
>
> ```
>  App1  AID = 010203040501
>  App2  AID = 010203040502
>  App3  AID = 010203040503
>  App4  AID = 010203040504
>  App5  AID = 010203040505
>  App6  AID = 010203040506
>  App7  AID = 010203040507
>  App8  AID = 010203040508
>  App9  AID = 010203040509
>  App10 AID = 01020304050a
>  App11 AID = 01020304050b
>  App12 AID = 01020304050c
>  App13 AID = 01020304050d
>  App14 AID = 01020304050e
>  App15 AID = 01020304050f
>  App16 AID = 010203040510
>  App17 AID = 010203040511
>  App18 AID = 010203040512
>  App19 AID = 010203040513
>  App20 AID = 010203040514
>  App21 AID = 010203040515
>  App22 AID = 010203040516
> ```

Look :

```
gp: gp -list
AID: A000000151000000 (|....Q...|)
     ISD OP_READY: Security Domain, Card lock, Card terminate, Default selected,
 CVM (PIN) management

AID: A0000001515350 (|....QSP|)
     ExM LOADED: (none)
     A000000151535041 (|....QSPA|)


gp: gp -install e:\PackageWithShortAIDs.cap

gp: gp -list
AID: A000000151000000 (|....Q...|)
     ISD OP_READY: Security Domain, Card lock, Card terminate, Default selected,
 CVM (PIN) management

AID: 010203040507 (|......|)
     App SELECTABLE: (none)

AID: A0000001515350 (|....QSP|)
     ExM LOADED: (none)
     A000000151535041 (|....QSPA|)

AID: 0102030405 (|.....|)
     ExM LOADED: (none)
     010203040507 (|......|)
     010203040506 (|......|)
     010203040505 (|......|)
     010203040504 (|......|)
     010203040503 (|......|)
     010203040502 (|......|)
     010203040501 (|......|)
     010203040513 (|......|)
     010203040512 (|......|)
     010203040511 (|......|)
     010203040510 (|......|)
     01020304050F (|......|)
     01020304050E (|......|)
     01020304050D (|......|)
     01020304050C (|......|)
     01020304050B (|......|)
     01020304050A (|......|)
     010203040516 (|......|)
     010203040515 (|......|)
     010203040514 (|......|)
     010203040509 (|......|)
     010203040508 (|......|)  
gp:
```

Now,I change I change the AID of Applets as below (everything else is the same as for before) :

> Package AID = 0102030405
>
> ```
>  App1  AID = 0102030405060708090001
>  App2  AID = 0102030405060708090002
>  App3  AID = 0102030405060708090003
>  App4  AID = 0102030405060708090004
>  App5  AID = 0102030405060708090005
>  App6  AID = 0102030405060708090006
>  App7  AID = 0102030405060708090007
>  App8  AID = 0102030405060708090008
>  App9  AID = 0102030405060708090009
>  App10 AID = 010203040506070809000a
>  App11 AID = 010203040506070809000b
>  App12 AID = 010203040506070809000c
>  App13 AID = 010203040506070809000d
>  App14 AID = 010203040506070809000e
>  App15 AID = 010203040506070809000f
>  App16 AID = 0102030405060708090010
>  App17 AID = 0102030405060708090011
>  App18 AID = 0102030405060708090012
>  App19 AID = 0102030405060708090013
>  App20 AID = 0102030405060708090014
>  App21 AID = 0102030405060708090015
>  App22 AID = 0102030405060708090016
> ```

In this case, I can load and install it. But I **can't** list my installed applets anymore!

```
gp: gp -list
AID: A000000151000000 (|....Q...|)
     ISD OP_READY: Security Domain, Card lock, Card terminate, Default selected,
 CVM (PIN) management

AID: A0000001515350 (|....QSP|)
     ExM LOADED: (none)
     A000000151535041 (|....QSPA|)


gp: gp -install e:\PackageWithLongAIDs.cap

gp: gp -list
javax.smartcardio.CardException: Get Status failed, SW: 6A88
        at pro.javacard.gp.GlobalPlatform.getConcatenatedStatus(GlobalPlatform.j
ava:1020)
        at pro.javacard.gp.GlobalPlatform.getStatus(GlobalPlatform.java:1070)
        at pro.javacard.gp.GlobalPlatform.getRegistry(GlobalPlatform.java:673)
        at pro.javacard.gp.GPTool.main(GPTool.java:499)
Exception in thread "main" javax.smartcardio.CardException: Get Status failed, S
W: 6A88
        at pro.javacard.gp.GlobalPlatform.getConcatenatedStatus(GlobalPlatform.j
ava:1020)
        at pro.javacard.gp.GlobalPlatform.getStatus(GlobalPlatform.java:1070)
        at pro.javacard.gp.GlobalPlatform.getRegistry(GlobalPlatform.java:673)
        at pro.javacard.gp.GPTool.main(GPTool.java:499)

gp:
```

Why?!

**Update :**

**Debug Mode - Short AIDs :**

```
.
.
.
A>> T=1 (4+0008) 80500000 08 9F6EB47CB0E1F31F
A<< (0028+2) (70ms) 00004198001714974248FF0200BD548DC44808E7509B8AD3DEACC41F 900
0
Host challenge: 9F6EB47CB0E1F31F
Card challenge: 00BD548DC44808E7
Card reports SCP02 with version 255 keys
Master keys:
Version 0
ENC: Ver:0 ID:0 Type:DES3 Len:16 Value:404142434445464748494A4B4C4D4E4F
MAC: Ver:0 ID:0 Type:DES3 Len:16 Value:404142434445464748494A4B4C4D4E4F
KEK: Ver:0 ID:0 Type:DES3 Len:16 Value:404142434445464748494A4B4C4D4E4F
Sequnce counter: 00BD
Derived session keys:
Version 0
ENC: Ver:0 ID:0 Type:DES3 Len:16 Value:DAED14FD3E4D7E6DC2A87F618D5A9EAC
MAC: Ver:0 ID:0 Type:DES3 Len:16 Value:59AEDE4C2E3E891BB50AE82028E44BF0
KEK: Ver:0 ID:0 Type:DES3 Len:16 Value:4DD4DBE895A5CFC590D4B190BF0547AC
Verified card cryptogram: 509B8AD3DEACC41F
Calculated host cryptogram: 85D04425E8C0A4BA
A>> T=1 (4+0016) 84820100 10 85D04425E8C0A4BAB5F40665FC1D88EE
A<< (0000+2) (66ms) 9000
A>> T=1 (4+0010) 84F28000 0A 4F009E0E0DBD266DC260
A<< (0011+2) (46ms) 08A000000151000000019E 9000
A>> T=1 (4+0010) 84F24000 0A 4F0078DB90059DC6D376
A<< (0009+2) (44ms) 060102030405070700 9000
A>> T=1 (4+0010) 84F22000 0A 4F000EA20738A58D27B1
A<< (0018+2) (48ms) 07A000000151535001000501020304050100 9000
A>> T=1 (4+0010) 84F21000 0A 4F0006BC7C18D19E7BDB
A<< (0183+2) (101ms) 07A000000151535001000108A0000001515350410501020304050100160
60102030405070601020304050606010203040505060102030405040601020304050306010203040
50206010203040501060102030405130601020304051206010203040511060102030405100601020
304050F0601020304050E0601020304050D0601020304050C0601020304050B0601020304050A060
1020304051606010203040515060102030405140601020304050906010203040508 9000
AID: A000000151000000 (|....Q...|)
     ISD OP_READY: Security Domain, Card lock, Card terminate, Default selected,
 CVM (PIN) management

AID: 010203040507 (|......|)
     App SELECTABLE: (none)

AID: A0000001515350 (|....QSP|)
     ExM LOADED: (none)
     A000000151535041 (|....QSPA|)

AID: 0102030405 (|.....|)
     ExM LOADED: (none)
     010203040507 (|......|)
     010203040506 (|......|)
     010203040505 (|......|)
     010203040504 (|......|)
     010203040503 (|......|)
     010203040502 (|......|)
     010203040501 (|......|)
     010203040513 (|......|)
     010203040512 (|......|)
     010203040511 (|......|)
     010203040510 (|......|)
     01020304050F (|......|)
     01020304050E (|......|)
     01020304050D (|......|)
     01020304050C (|......|)
     01020304050B (|......|)
     01020304050A (|......|)
     010203040516 (|......|)
     010203040515 (|......|)
     010203040514 (|......|)
     010203040509 (|......|)
     010203040508 (|......|)

SCardEndTransaction()
SCardDisconnect("ACS CCID USB Reader 0", false)

gp:
```

**Debug Mode - Long AIDs :**

```
.
. 
.
A>> T=1 (4+0008) 80500000 08 E81EAC2B833E5DCF
A<< (0028+2) (70ms) 00004198001714974248FF0200B93785186688F163331EF41FA02CB8 900
0
Host challenge: E81EAC2B833E5DCF
Card challenge: 00B93785186688F1
Card reports SCP02 with version 255 keys
Master keys:
Version 0
ENC: Ver:0 ID:0 Type:DES3 Len:16 Value:404142434445464748494A4B4C4D4E4F
MAC: Ver:0 ID:0 Type:DES3 Len:16 Value:404142434445464748494A4B4C4D4E4F
KEK: Ver:0 ID:0 Type:DES3 Len:16 Value:404142434445464748494A4B4C4D4E4F
Sequnce counter: 00B9
Derived session keys:
Version 0
ENC: Ver:0 ID:0 Type:DES3 Len:16 Value:1EC5FBCA9A5F21F727C14461A7D7E2C6
MAC: Ver:0 ID:0 Type:DES3 Len:16 Value:2688CFFD58CCF9EB52B5D5E786364C89
KEK: Ver:0 ID:0 Type:DES3 Len:16 Value:C181FE8094950965495E0D5023AFD65D
Verified card cryptogram: 63331EF41FA02CB8
Calculated host cryptogram: A269860A0E584230
A>> T=1 (4+0016) 84820100 10 A269860A0E5842301E0CBE71E485EA79
A<< (0000+2) (66ms) 9000
A>> T=1 (4+0010) 84F28000 0A 4F00DF01359AC330E966
A<< (0011+2) (46ms) 08A000000151000000019E 9000
A>> T=1 (4+0010) 84F24000 0A 4F003E447E78BC4DE5CC
A<< (0014+2) (45ms) 0B01020304050607080900070700 9000
A>> T=1 (4+0010) 84F22000 0A 4F00D20EAEA9E44363C1
A<< (0018+2) (48ms) 07A000000151535001000501020304050100 9000
A>> T=1 (4+0010) 84F21000 0A 4F003EA1383F26463052
A<< (0020+2) (54ms) 07A000000151535001000108A000000151535041 6310
A>> T=1 (4+0010) 84F21001 0A 4F002196E82C3A537F62
A<< (0000+2) (50ms) 6A88
javax.smartcardio.CardException: Get Status failed, SW: 6A88
        at pro.javacard.gp.GlobalPlatform.getConcatenatedStatus(GlobalPlatform.j
ava:1020)
        at pro.javacard.gp.GlobalPlatform.getStatus(GlobalPlatform.java:1070)
        at pro.javacard.gp.GlobalPlatform.getRegistry(GlobalPlatform.java:673)
        at pro.javacard.gp.GPTool.main(GPTool.java:499)
SCardEndTransaction()
SCardDisconnect("ACS CCID USB Reader 0", false)
Exception in thread "main" javax.smartcardio.CardException: Get Status failed, S
W: 6A88
        at pro.javacard.gp.GlobalPlatform.getConcatenatedStatus(GlobalPlatform.j
ava:1020)
        at pro.javacard.gp.GlobalPlatform.getStatus(GlobalPlatform.java:1070)
        at pro.javacard.gp.GlobalPlatform.getRegistry(GlobalPlatform.java:673)
        at pro.javacard.gp.GPTool.main(GPTool.java:499)

gp:
```

**Test with another Card :**

I upload this package on another card (another type), but it is OK!

```
gp: gp -list
AID: A000000003000000 (|........|)
     ISD OP_READY: Security Domain, Card lock, Card terminate, Default selected,
 CVM (PIN) management


gp: gp -install e:\PackageWithLongAIDs.cap

gp: gp -list
AID: A000000003000000 (|........|)
     ISD OP_READY: Security Domain, Card lock, Card terminate, Default selected,
 CVM (PIN) management

AID: 0102030405060708090007 (|...........|)
     App SELECTABLE: (none)

AID: 0102030405 (|.....|)
     Exe LOADED: (none) 

gp:
```

As you see above, the list of applets of my package doesn't appear in output(I think it is a feature of SD of my card), but I have output without any error.

I think the card is the origin of the error! No?

Note that, This problem appear only in cases that the package contains more than **20** applets.

Comment: GP uses combined calls to the applet here, it doesn't issue one single APDU but multiple calls. This means that this could well be a programming error. Maybe you could debug `gp` to find out which APDU is responsible for generating the "reference not found" status word.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I added the output of `gp -list -v -d` for both cases. Would you please help me to find out the bug? thank you very much. :)

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I tried whole of my test with another card also. It works fine in the new card. Can I conclude that there is something wrong with my card (and not with the GP tool)?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes btw, Another question appears for me! Why I don't have the list of applets of my package in the output of new card? (I mean why I can't see 20 AIDs like the output of previous card's output for ShortAID package)? Is it a feature fo cards to return those AIDs or not?

Comment: It's probably the value of P2 in the failing command, it's the only thing that seems out of kilt.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes But Status Words of its previous command are different also. For ShortAIDs package, the card respond with a bunch of data followed by a `SW=9000` while for the LongAIDs package it respond with a little data that is followed with a `SW=6310`

Comment: 6310 means more data available if I take a quick look at the GP specs  . It may be that the GP implementation does not handle this well or that the card implementation is faulty in this regard. It is not often that this situation would occur.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Working fine with the new card, doesn't mean the GP is OK?

Comment: Does that other card also send 6310? If not, then the GP may not handle 6310 well. If it does send 6310 then the one failing card is not correct, or both the GP *and* the other card is incorrect (and trust me, that's also possible, although less likely).

Answer (score -1):

If you have troubles with specific software, **please follow the documentation of the software** to get help (this includes posting to the right place and posting with sufficient information, like logs with -d -v for GlobalPlatformPro and do open a github issue if you think you have found a bug)

If you have questions about JavaCard or GlobalPlatform, **please read the specifications** before asking questions that are explained in the specs (like different VM limitations).

Comment: Thank you dear Martin.
I think I have trouble with my card! My card issuer claim that the card is Java Card 3.01 and GP2.2.1 compliant. I searched GP Spec and JC3.0.1  Specifications for a line that indicate maximum applets reside in a package is 20 member. But I found nothing. And as I tried tools such as JCManager and Opensc-tool and GPJ also, and nothing changed, I conclude the problem is about the card. And as the issuer not answers my questions, I asked it here.Do you think Is there any problem?

Comment: And if you are the down-voter, I didn't satisfied with your reasons! All the questions here (In SO), Are related to misunderstanding some Specification or some tools manuals.

Comment: There is misunderstanding and there is not trying hard enough. You're also asking two rather separate questions as well. Martin, these are comments, not answers. Voted both Q and A down. Am1r, at least get your APDU handling in the `process()` method straight.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I find out a relation between the Applet's AIDs and the problem and update the question, would you please take a look at it? It is only one question.

Comment: Dear Martin, would you please take another look at the question? It is updated. Is it a bug in your tool or it is related with my card?